# Good folding/indenting for Rails.js.erb for Javascript/Jquery in Vim?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vim, indentation, folding

I'm fairly new to vim/Macvim and am wondering if someone could kindly direct me to a plugin or resource on getting good indenting and folding in Vim for ruby on rails javascript erb files that are a mixture of javascript+jquery which have some server-side calls mixed in.

I know it's a tall order with essentially 3-syntaxes being intermingled but I'm guessing someone's already solved this beast.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with Vim/MacVim and Ruby compatibility. The first time, I installed using Homebrew and ended up scrapping that version and compiling Vim from source. It's more work but you can specify the language support that is compiled and things work much better. [This](http://nerderati.com/2010/07/compiling-vim-with-ruby-integration-on-snow-leopard/) post has a good step-by-step guide on compiling Vim on Mac. Try that and then see if you still have issues with `js.erb` files

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the file is written you may be able to fold on indentation level. This can be done by passing "**:set foldmethod=indent**" while in a ViM file. More information on ViM folding can be found here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Folding